# Label states in QGIS with county-level shape

Tags: qgis, labeling

I want to label state names in QGIS but my original shapefile is built in county-level. If I simply label them with `State`, my map shows multiple labels in each state as my original file (one label for each county).

Is there any way to to that in QGIS?

Comment: The file I was using can be found here: http://cdmaps.polisci.ucla.edu; scrolling down the page and you shall find "district001.zip"

Answer (score 1):

Use dissolve to merge the county polygons to state polygons and label those.

Vector | Geoprocessing tools | Dissolve

Comment: Yes I did that way but I had two bugs: it generated several unnecessary lines and dots in some states, which made it pretty ugly; when doing this, 2 counties were lost and I don't know why.

Comment: Does it matter? Does it impact the labeling result?